# Ezekiel 39:28 NIV vs BSB, gather or regather?

Tags: ezekiel

Ezekiel 39:28
New International Version

> Then they will know that I am the LORD their God, for though I sent them into exile among the nations, I will **gather** them to their own land, not leaving any behind.

Berean Study Bible

> Then they will know that I am the LORD their God, when I **regather** them to their own land, not leaving any of them behind after their exile among the nations.

Is there a difference between "gather" and "regather"?

Comment: both have same meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operative word here is כָּנַס (kanas) which simply means, "to gather, collect".  It only occurs 11 times in the OT, 1 Chron 22;2, Neh 12:44, Est 4:16, Ps 33:7, 147:2, Eccl 2:8, 26, 3:5, Isa 28:20, Eze 22;21, 29:28.

In this final occurrence in Eze 39:28, the word simply means, as usual, "to gather".  The context suggests that this is a prophecy of the time, then still future, when God will call the Jews back from the lands to which they had been sent into exile.  Inasmuch as this would be a gathering for the second time (after the first time at the exodus from Egypt) it could be called a "regathering", but that would be interpretive.

Perhaps there is a sense that before the dispersal to their lands of exile, the Jews were already gathered in their land and after the exile they will return during the regathering; again this is interpretive.

Most versions simply and correctly render the word "gather" (or equivalent), eg, NIV, NLT, ESV, NKJV, NASB, Amplified, ASV, CEV, ERV, ISV, JPS, NET, NHEB, WEB, YLT, etc.  Only the CSB, BSB and HCSB have "regather".